# Angular js :-> angular throws unknown provider error while accessing resolve proprerty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when i remove ng-controller from view ,resolve property works perfectly fine but when i put ng-controller in template,it throws unknown provider.can any body help me out why this is happening??

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'page/login.html',
                controller: 'loginController',
                resolve: {
                    message: function(demoService){
                        return demoService.getResolveContent();
                    },
                    greeting: function(demoFactory){
                        return demoFactory.getGreeting();
                    }
                }

            }).
            when('/profile', {
                templateUrl: 'page/profile.html',
                controller: 'profileController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);
```

> function loginController($scope,$location,message,greeting){
>
> ```
>     $scope.tempfactory = greeting;
>
> }
> ```

```
<div style="color: white;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: lightgray" ng-controller="loginController">

    <p>{{tempfactory}}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="inputBoxValue">
    <button style="width: 100px;height: 100px" ng-click="profilePage()"></button>

</div>
```

If i replace above html with this:

```
<div style="color: white;width: 100%;height: 100%;background-color: lightgray" >

    <p>{{tempfactory}}</p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="inputBoxValue">
    <button style="width: 100px;height: 100px" ng-click="profilePage()"></button>

</div>
```

It worked perfectly fine.can any body tell me the reason of this.

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies added using `resolve` are injected as part of route being resolved and controller being created and are not available otherwise. These are not  global dependencies like a `service` or `filter`.

If you use `ng-controller` the route transition does not happen and route related dependency resolution  and controller creation does not take place and the DI error is raised.

If you put controller in route definition and using `ng-controller`, two controller instances are created, but one gives DI error.

Comment: Thanks man, this really help me to understand why my dynamic created controller return unresolved DI, which I manage to solve it with creating a child/different controller not dependent to the resolve provider